# Android app forces semi reboot / crash on some phones

Tags: java, android

The app in questions seems to work fine, but when you use the back button on the phone to exit the app sometimes it crashes the phone. It doesnt actually turn it off but runs the boot up animation again.

Here is an excert I have from logcat, this segment is repeated a lot of times. The app is a quiz so only relies on a database.

Any advice on how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated.

```
11-20 15:47:40.236: DEBUG/WifiStateTracker(1505): get mPhoneStateListener
11-20 15:47:41.087: DEBUG/SensorService(1505): enable: get sensor name = MPL accel
11-20 15:47:41.087: DEBUG/Sensors(1505): handle : 4 en: 1, v010.0 - Try to resolve lock issue
11-20 15:47:41.087: DEBUG/Sensors(1505): lock_status = 58
11-20 15:47:41.087: DEBUG/Sensors(1505): Andy: MPLSensor::enable: lock1
11-20 15:47:41.087: DEBUG/Sensors(1505): mEnabled = 0x10
11-20 15:47:41.087: DEBUG/Sensors(1505): set_power_states++: enabled_sensors: 16 dmp_started: 0
11-20 15:47:41.087: DEBUG/Sensors(1505): Before if statment: cs:0 rs:1 en_ped:0 da_ped:0 en_g:0 da_g:0
11-20 15:47:41.087: DEBUG/Sensors(1505): STOP timerirq_1
11-20 15:47:41.107: DEBUG/Sensors(1505): Starting DMP
11-20 15:47:41.127: INFO/(1505): mpu3050_resume: Resuming to 0070
11-20 15:47:41.127: DEBUG/Sensors(1505): Exit: Starting DMP
11-20 15:47:41.127: DEBUG/Sensors(1505): set_power_states--
11-20 15:47:41.127: DEBUG/Sensors(1505): Andy: MPLSensor::enable: unlock1
11-20 15:47:41.127: DEBUG/Sensors(1505): MPLSensor::enable--1
11-20 15:47:41.127: DEBUG/SensorService(1505): SensorDevice::activate--: handle = 0x4, enabled = 0x1
11-20 15:47:41.127: DEBUG/SensorService(1505): enable: sensor->activate return value = 0x0
11-20 15:47:41.127: DEBUG/SensorService(1505): enable: calling mActiveSensors.add(handle, rec) = (0x4, 0x7a40e8)
11-20 15:47:41.127: DEBUG/SensorService(1505): enable: mActiveConnections.indexOf(connection) = 0x0
11-20 15:47:41.127: DEBUG/SensorService(1505): pid=1505, uid=1000
11-20 15:47:41.127: DEBUG/SensorService(1505): disable: get sensor name = MPL accel
11-20 15:47:41.127: DEBUG/SensorService(1505): disable: sensor = 0x326a98
11-20 15:47:41.127: DEBUG/Sensors(1505): handle : 4 en: 0, v010.0 - Try to resolve lock issue
11-20 15:47:41.127: DEBUG/Sensors(1505): lock_status = 63
11-20 15:47:41.127: DEBUG/Sensors(1505): Andy: MPLSensor::enable: lock1
11-20 15:47:41.127: WARN/MPL-sup(1505): MLGetAKMComassStatus, gAKMCompassStatus = 0
11-20 15:47:41.127: DEBUG/Sensors(1505): mEnabled = 0x0
11-20 15:47:41.127: DEBUG/Sensors(1505): set_power_states++: enabled_sensors: 0 dmp_started: 1
11-20 15:47:41.127: DEBUG/Sensors(1505): Before if statment: cs:0 rs:0 en_ped:0 da_ped:0 en_g:0 da_g:0
11-20 15:47:41.127: DEBUG/Sensors(1505): Stopping DMP
11-20 15:47:41.127: INFO/(1505): mpu3050_suspend: suspending sensors to 0000
11-20 15:47:41.127: INFO/(1505): mpu3050_suspend: Will resume next to 0070
11-20 15:47:41.127: DEBUG/Sensors(1505): inside if(s_use_timerirq)
11-20 15:47:41.157: DEBUG/Sensors(1505): set_power_states--
11-20 15:47:41.157: DEBUG/Sensors(1505): Andy: MPLSensor::enable: unlock1
11-20 15:47:41.157: DEBUG/Sensors(1505): MPLSensor::enable--1
11-20 15:47:41.157: DEBUG/SensorService(1505): SensorDevice::activate--: handle = 0x4, enabled = 0x0
11-20 15:47:41.157: DEBUG/SensorService(1505): pid=1505, uid=1000
11-20 15:47:41.167: DEBUG/SensorService(1505): enable: get sensor name = MPL accel
11-20 15:47:41.167: DEBUG/Sensors(1505): handle : 4 en: 1, v010.0 - Try to resolve lock issue
11-20 15:47:41.167: DEBUG/Sensors(1505): lock_status = 58
11-20 15:47:41.167: DEBUG/Sensors(1505): Andy: MPLSensor::enable: lock1
11-20 15:47:41.167: DEBUG/Sensors(1505): mEnabled = 0x10
11-20 15:47:41.167: DEBUG/Sensors(1505): set_power_states++: enabled_sensors: 16 dmp_started: 0
11-20 15:47:41.167: DEBUG/Sensors(1505): Before if statment: cs:0 rs:1 en_ped:0 da_ped:0 en_g:0 da_g:0
11-20 15:47:41.167: DEBUG/Sensors(1505): STOP timerirq_1
11-20 15:47:41.187: DEBUG/Sensors(1505): Starting DMP
11-20 15:47:41.207: INFO/(1505): mpu3050_resume: Resuming to 0070
```

Edit:

The way I can guarantee this to happen is as follows.
From activity A(home screen) open activity B (Question page) click an option and that takes you to activity C(Answer page) Here you click next and go back to activity B.
So B -> C -> B

If I go through this process a lot answering around 10 - 15 questions. When I click back to A i get the logcat output above. Then when I click back from the home page (A) it does this reboot thing.

I have a suspicion that this is something to do with how I am handling the intents when looping.

Extract from B that forward to C

```
public void answer(int picked){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, package.Answer.class);
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putInt("PICKED", picked);
    b.putInt("CORRECT", correct);
    b.putString("RANDOM", "nextq");
    intent.putExtras(b);
        this.startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
```

}

Extract from C that takes you back to B

```
public void nextquestion(){
    Intent Intent = new Intent(this, package.Question.class);
    startActivity(Intent);
    this.setResult(1, Intent);
    this.finish();
}
```

Extract from B when returning from C

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    this.finish();
}
```

Comment: Are you making use of the device Sensors in your app?

Comment: no not at all unless a database counts

Comment: Have you tried this on other devices? Also, you're not overriding onBackPressed(), are you?

Comment: No I'm not overriding onBackPressed. It is crashing on around 4 phones I have tested it on but not 4 others. These are all different types of devices.

Comment: Max, if it's when the BACK button is pressed from within a SPECIFIC activity, could you post the code of that Activity? Also, are subclassing Application anywhere? Just trying to figure out what's going on in your app..

Comment: We might be able to see the reason for the device restart if you can capture the logcat output filtered to only show the system_server process. In Eclipse you can do this by creating a "by PID: 52" filter in the Logcat viewer, or use `adb logcat | grep " 52):"` from the command line (where 52 is the system_server PID, visible in the "Devices" window in Eclipse or from `adb shell ps | grep system_server`).

Comment: @LuxuryMode I have provided some more detail above

Comment: @Max, please paste us the relevant code sections.

Comment: @LuxuryMode I have included extracts that I have a feeling are relevant. I didnt post more as it would be hundreds of lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Activity C, get rid of `startActivity`. All you need is `setResult(int, intent)`. While we're at it, please please change your variable name to lower case `intent`. Only use capitalized `Intent` when referencing the type.

Also, what's the point of `onActivityResult` in activity B if you simply `finish` the `Activity` when you get the result?

Comment: Do you mean get rid of startActivity?

Comment: Thanks for your help. It really has made my day that I can get this working. After your advice I took a look and actually did your second suggestion. Worked a treat.